# Why Isn't a Mocha Test Failing When Returning false

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

Shouldn't a mocha test fail if you straight up do a `return false;`?  Mine is still passing.  Why?

```
 describe('some description', function(){
                it('should do something', function (){
                    return false;
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [mocha documentation](http://mochajs.org/#getting-started):

> Mocha allows you to use any assertion library you want, if it throws an error, it will work! This means you can utilize libraries such as should.js, node's regular assert module, or others.

So if you want your test to fail throw an Error

```
describe('some description', function() {
  it('should do something', function() {
    throw new Error();
  });
});
```

Comment: ah so it's not based on true/false being returned by whatever assertion library's assertion being called.  I would have assumed true/false but this isn't the case I guess.  I guess I didn't infer that you have to throw an error.  I'm used to tests in .NET where asserts in line NUnit for example does return true/false as the ultimate value that determines pass/fail

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the following approach:

```
describe('some description', function() {
  it('should do something', function() {
    done("Your error message");
  });
});
```